# NopCommerece with web platform installer - Sql Error

Tags: .net, sql-server, nopcommerce, web-platform-installer

While trying to install nopCommerce using web platform installer I got an error, that my Login isn't valid.

[image]

but when i try to login Sql with same Userid & password, I login successfully.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you rechecked the credentials and you are sure you have right credentials then I think application is not able to connect your Sql server, reason could be your SQL server firewall in blocking requests from your application server IP